# Which version of AspectJ is suitable for Java 1.4.2?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I can seem to find an guide for 1.4.2 compatibility.

Can someone who is good in AOP give me a heads up.

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the latest version.  You just won't be able to define your aspect with

```
@Aspect annotation
```

But you can write your aspects the 'old way' and it will work.

I also recommend you dowload the AJDT plugin for eclipse.  When developing your aspects it give you visual hints on :

```
all the methods/class advised by a pointcut
advices all over your codebase.
```

Very helpful during dev. phase.

Answer (score 2):

Read [the page you linked](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php):

> The AspectJ compiler produces programs for any version of the Java platform (jdk1.1 and later). The compiler itself requires Java2 (1.4 or later) to run.

or the [FAQ, which that page links to](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.html#q:compability):

> **What Java versions does AspectJ require and support?**
>
> The AspectJ compiler produces programs for any released version of the Java platform (jdk1.1 and later). When running, your program classes must be able to reach classes in the small (< 100K) runtime library (aspectjrt.jar) from the distribution. The tools themselves require J2SE 1.3 or later to run, but the compiler can produce classes for any 1.1-compliant version of the Java platform.